# How to resize UILabels to fit content?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

My program currently has thirty UILabels that may contain numbers between one and three digits. I want my UILabels to expand and shrink horizontally as the numbers within them change size. At the moment the text is shrinking and the UILabels size remains the same.

If this can be done just using the xib file this would be preferable to doing so programmatically but if this isn't possible either would be great.

Thanks

Comment: How about make the size of UILabel fit for 3 digits all the time?

Comment: Haha dunno why I didn't think of this. It will look a bit tacky but I will do this if I can't find a way to expand the UILabel itself. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After setting the text of the label, call `sizeToFit` on the label. This will make the label just big enough for the text.

BTW - why do you need to do this? Why not just make the labels big enough for the possible values and leave them that size? What benefit do you think you will get by shrinking the labels?

Comment: Because one of the labels has three numbers in and but it will be very rare it will have three three digit numbers. It's hard to explain but within the context of the app it would look pretty tacky as some labels will be be very under filled. Thanks I'll accept this when I'm allowed to, I couldn't find this method anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: `sizeToFit` is a method of `UIView`. `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView`. How can a label look tacky is it's underfilled? As long as you make the label's background color `[UIColor clearColor]` then the extra size will be invisible.

Comment: I have black backgrounds on the labels I wish to keep.

Comment: @Deco That kind of information is important and should have been mentioned up front since it has a big impact on the look.

Comment: Is there anyway to control the direction of the views expansion?
For some of my labels I need to expand to the left rather than the right so my views remain aligned:
http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/200/screenshot20121114at201.png