# Adding space/padding to a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, padding

I have a `UILabel` where I want to add space in the top and in the bottom. With the minimum height in constraints, I've modified it to:

[image]

To do this I've used:

```
override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 10.0)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}
```

But I've to find a different method because if I write more than two lines, the problem is the same:

[image]

Comment: We finally finally figured out exactly how to do this properly, in all dynamic cases, as a perfect drop-in replacement for UILabel with no need to re-layout or any other issues. PHEW.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Answer (score 147, accepted):

If you want to stick with UILabel, without subclassing it, [Mundi has given you a clear solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel/27460983#27460983).

If alternatively, you would be willing to avoid wrapping the UILabel with a UIView, you could use UITextView to enable the use of UIEdgeInsets (padding) or subclass UILabel to support UIEdgeInsets.

Using a **UITextView** would only need to provide the insets (Objective-C):

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

Alternative, if you subclass **UILabel**, an example to this approach would be overriding the **drawTextInRect** method 
(Objective-C)

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)uiLabelRect {
    UIEdgeInsets myLabelInsets = {10, 0, 10, 0};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(uiLabelRect, myLabelInsets)];
}
```

You could additionally provide your new subclassed UILabel with insets variables for TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM and RIGHT.

An example code could be:

**In .h (Objective-C)**

```
float topInset, leftInset,bottomInset, rightInset;
```

**In .m (Objective-C)**

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)uiLabelRect {
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(uiLabelRect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset,leftInset,bottomInset,rightInset))];
}
```

From what I have seen, it seems you have to override the intrinsicContentSize of the UILabel when subclassing it.

So you should override **intrinsicContentSize** like:

```
- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize {
    CGSize intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = [super intrinsicContentSize] ;
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset ;
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset ;
    return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize ;
}
```

And add the following method to edit your insets, instead of editing them individually:

```
- (void) setContentEdgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)edgeInsets {
    topInset = edgeInsets.top;
    leftInset = edgeInsets.left;
    rightInset = edgeInsets.right;
    bottomInset = edgeInsets.bottom;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] ;
}
```

It will update the size of your UILabel to match the edge insets and cover the multiline necessity you referred to.

After searching a bit I have found this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/2596057) with an IPInsetLabel. If none of those solutions work you could try it out.

There was a similar question (duplicate) about this matter. 
For a full list of available solutions, see this answer: **[UILabel text margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin)**

Comment: Sorry but I've alreay used: `   
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 10.0)
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
        
    }
    ` it doesn't work because the result is the same, don't work dynamically..

Comment: Did you tried with a UITextView instead of a UILabel? Or do you really need to use an UILabel?

Comment: @Annachiara check the edit I've made. See if it works.

Comment: Ok. Did it work the textview? Sorry for not writing in Swift but I am still in Obj-C mode. My goal with that code was to help you reach some conclusion. Hope it did.

Comment: Using TextView and some storyboard settings and     
        self.textview.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 10, 10);    It finally works ! Thanks !

Comment: The result was returned in `intrinsicContentSize` method will be wrong when `leftInset` and `rightInset` increase, b/c the width of label will be narrowed but the height not increase, so a part of text will be disappeared. To resolve this problem you need to re-calculate the height of text and assign it to `intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height`. I also posted an answer in this thread.

Comment: I think [this answer is better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21267507/2604204)  because works fine with `sizeToFit`.

Comment: overriding drawTextInRect cannot work correctly for NSAttributedString

Comment: Note that if you add to the `[super intrinsicContentSize]` and it is already at its max value because you didn't set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, you will get this extremely cryptic error: "This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future."

Comment: `UITextView` FTW! Why customize when you can substitute for a native component?

Comment: This fails when the text *happens to be certain lengths*.  I included an image example in the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884  it's taken some 10 years for everyone to figure out exactly how to do this, geesh!

Comment: Guys, UITextView is useless - it does not size to fit easily.  UILabel has many, many advantages.

Comment: It's unfortunate for people googling here that this absolutely wrong, 10 yr old answer, is ticked as correct!

Answer (score 308):

I have tried with it on **Swift 4.2**, hopefully it work for you!

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
                      height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
    }   

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            // ensures this works within stack views if multi-line
            preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.width - (leftInset + rightInset)
        }
    } 
}
```

Or you can use CocoaPods here https://github.com/levantAJ/PaddingLabel

`pod 'PaddingLabel', '1.2'`

[image]

Comment: The uilabel width is not changing, causing the text become "..."

Comment: Please how do I implement it

Comment: @Tai Le , thanks for sharing, I have used it in tableview, I don't know why its triming the text , eg. student becomes studen,

Comment: Note that if you add to the `super.intrinsicContentSize` and it is already at its max value because you didn't set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, you will get this extremely cryptic error: "This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future."

Comment: @Tim maybe you've meant to use `min`

Comment: @ielyamani you are correct, I did mean that - will delete comment and post a new one with `min`

Comment: Changing the return statement to `return CGSize(width: min(size.width + leftInset + rightInset, 10000), height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)` solved the issue

Comment: A word of warning here. I've been using this solution in a UILabel subclass. When using these labels in multiline mode, in a vertical UIStackView, there's an issue. Sometimes the label seems to wrap the text without correctly sizing the label - so a word or 2 ends up missing from the end of the string. I don't have a solution right now. I'll write it up here if I make one. I spent hours poking at this issue, before proving it was here.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution does not work in a vertical UIStackView with multiple lines.

Comment: To make it work in those situations, you need to override "setBounds" and set self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth to the bounds' width, minus your left and right insets

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is quite wrong. It fails in many cases.  The first image HERE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884 is exactly an example of how it fails.

Comment: This is the only solution that works with multi-line autolayout as well as with single-line out of many I tried. Thanks!

Comment: @mkll - it absolutely does not work at all.  (It works "sometimes" if by chance the line length is a certain length.  You can clearly and obviously see an example of it not working, with an image example, right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Comment: hi @DarrenBlack just noticed your comment. as you say this doesn't work at all.  as you say it takes hours and hours to figure out what is happening - it's fully explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Comment: I did a version that also allows specifying a border (color, width, corner radius) based on this answer and another answer here (Fattie's answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/826946. My question and answer are over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317976/826946

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, at all, in Swift anything, @LanceSamaria :)

Comment: it makes no difference at all if you override var bounds, @ReimondHill .  **The answer is simply completely wrong.** A number of people have given actual example images of it being broken.  It's just, simply, completely wrong. It only "works" in the simplest of situations where there's one text alone with nothing below it and it happens to "work" because the text length is, by luck, correct.

Answer (score 94):

**Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

   @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
   @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
   @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 5.0
   @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 5.0

   override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
      let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
      super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
   }

   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
      get {
         var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
         contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
         contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
         return contentSize
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: just a little comment: set this class to label in identity inspector(custom class) and use new  attribute in attribute inspector named label padding. also below 5 padding is effectless

Comment: This doesn't always work correctly with multiline labels, because when the label calculates its height, it assumes zero padding.

Answer (score 92):

You can do it properly from IB :

1. change the text to attributed

[image: attributed text]

2. go to dropdown list with "..."

[image]

3. you will see some padding properties for the lines, paragraphs and text change indent first line or anything you want

[image]

4. check the result

[image]

Comment: In my storyboard I can see the text change but when I run the app. The text doesn´t show the change... T_T.. my label is inside of an custom cell, are there any problem?

Comment: @A.Trejo May be your custom cell set the label property at run time.

Comment: In SB right margin can't has negative value. Do it in code. `style.tailIndent = -30.0`. Still can't do top and bottom indent.

Comment: Changes can appear on storyboard but when you run the app there are no changes.

Comment: This is not applicable when you set text programatically.

Comment: This is not the answer. You have only control over the first line indent, bot not the padding in all directions.

Comment: I used the combination of "height multiple" and "spacing" properties of the attributed text in the IB to achieve desired padding on top and bottom respectively.

Answer (score 72):

Just use a UIButton, its already built in. Turn off all the extra button features and  you have a label that you can set edge instets on.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
button.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
button.tintColor = .white // this will be the textColor
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Hey this is a great tip! No extensions required! :-D

Comment: Setting `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` is handy to disable it.

Comment: Great tip... I'd rather do this than going for an extension.

Comment: Nice tip, with the big advantage that it can also be done in the Interface Builder

Comment: The best solution without subclassing and etc.

Comment: Mind blown. Amazing solution here!

Comment: Really the simplest solution. You can autosize the button with `button.sizeToFit()` after setting the title which is harder when embedding a label in a view.

Comment: A `UITextView` is better than this solution when it comes to not needing to subclass. This is because Voice Over will treat it as a button instead. Please care about users with accessibility needs - one day it could be you.

Comment: ContentEdgeInsets was deprecated in iOS 15 and will be ignored now.

Answer (score 65):

Just use a `UIView` as a superview and define a fixed margin to the label with auto layout.

Comment: `drawTextInRect ` works only for 1 line, `intrinsicContentSize` does not work with horizontal padding. Wrap UILabel inside UIView is the good way to go

Comment: If you're in IB, now is the time to remember the menu Editor -> Embed In -> View. Just select your UILabel first :)

Comment: This is by far I see as the easiest solution. One just needs to make sure to align label in the center (horizontally and vertically) over the view and also update the view's bg color to match the bg color of your UILabel.

Comment: If you need to update and resize the `UILabel` dynamically, create the `UIView` independently of the label (not as a super view), then Auto Layout will adjust `UIView` as the label resizes.

Comment: The proposition is interesting, just to take into account that in UITesting a label will be inside an 'other' element, and secondly those constraints between label and container have 1000 priority so when compressing a view for small screens this can be something to hack

Answer (score 59):

**SWIFT 4**

Easy to use solution, available for all UILabel child in project.

**Example:**

```
let label = UILabel()
    label.<Do something>
    label.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

**UILabel Extension**

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var padding = UIEdgeInsets()
    }

    public var padding: UIEdgeInsets? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding) as? UIEdgeInsets
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding, newValue as UIEdgeInsets?, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let insets = padding {
            self.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
        } else {
            self.drawText(in: rect)
        }
    }

    override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let text = self.text else { return super.intrinsicContentSize }

        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        var textWidth: CGFloat = frame.size.width
        var insetsHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        var insetsWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

        if let insets = padding {
            insetsWidth += insets.left + insets.right
            insetsHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom
            textWidth -= insetsWidth
        }

        let newSize = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.font], context: nil)

        contentSize.height = ceil(newSize.size.height) + insetsHeight
        contentSize.width = ceil(newSize.size.width) + insetsWidth

        return contentSize
    }
}
```

Comment: please briefly explain your answer, and do not only post code.

Comment: Your extension cancel the 0 value to numberOfLines

Comment: This is great, but Im having issues with multiple lines, even thought I add numbers of lines 2 or leave at 0, it always shows one. you know how to solve it?

Comment: @AntoineBodart did you manage to solve the numberOfLines problem?

Comment: @ AntoineBodart, @Mago Nicolas Palacios - Was Solved!

Comment: @podkorytov how did you solve it? I need it as well :D

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios fix bug in "intrinsicContentSize".

Comment: @podkorytov now quite sure I understand what you mean, can you put the code?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios, current code is correct! Enjoy.

Comment: @podkorytov thanks, but it actually crashes :D https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfp0dc58yqwior4/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-09%20at%2012.11.30%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios fixed.

Comment: Good idea, but i would be cautious using associated keys inside an extension like this; especially if it is a large project with a big team. While extensions are pretty great, i think subclassing here is safer. But that's just IMHO.

Comment: Easy to use maybe, not very easy to follow.

Comment: @Wez what do you mean? explain please.

Comment: XCode10.1 Error `'inset(by:)' has been renamed to 'UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(_:_:)'`

Comment: this will override all labels I think. I have an issue with my alerts now being cut off

Comment: I highly do NOT recommend this usage, it will affect all labels in your project, which will lead to some of them misplaced and word-wrap!

Comment: @iEvgenPodkorytov yes, it brokes my labels all over the app, especially navigation bar titles.

I recommend this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45345261/7987502

Comment: Do not override methods using an extension. This is very bad practice.
See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274660/4698501

Comment: As others have pointed out, this will alter all labels in your project. I wasted so much time trying to figure out why everything broke (changed multiple things at once, so didn’t remember adding this extension), and only when I reverted my last commit did I realize this was the reason. I recommend using a class instead.

Answer (score 33):

We finally figured a **full and correct solution** which works in **all** cases, including **stack views, dynamic cells, dynamic number of lines, collection views, animated padding, any character count**, and every other situation.

### Padding a `UILabel`, full solution.  Updated for 2024.

Turns out there are *three things*:

### 1. Must call textRect#forBounds *with the new smaller size*

### 2. Must override drawText with the new smaller size

### 3. If a dynamically sized cell, must adjust intrinsicContentSize

In the visual example below the text unit is in a table view or similar which gives it a **fixed width**.

We take the "existing" intrinsicContentSize ***and actually add to the height***.

> You have to literally "get" the height calculated **"so far"** by the engine, and **change** that value.

(IMO it would be clearer if Apple exposed something like "preliminary height calculation", but that's not how it is.)

Secondly we have to actually use the `textRect#forBounds` call ***with our new smaller size***.

So in `textRect#forBounds` we ***first*** make the size smaller and ***ONLY THEN*** call super.

### Alert!  You *must* call super *after*, not before!

Notice some solutions seem to **USUALLY** work. If you call super "in the wrong order", it **USUALLY** works, but fails for **CERTAIN SPECIFIC** text lengths.

Here is an exact visual example of "incorrectly doing super first":

[image]

The margins are correct **BUT the size calculation is actually wrong**, because it was done with the "super first" in `textRect#forBounds`.

Fixed:

Only now does the `textRect#forBounds` engine **know how to do the calculation properly**:

[image]

Finally!

Phew!

```
class PaddyLabel: UILabel {

    // as desired:
    let UIEI = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 24)
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize:CGSize {
        numberOfLines = 0
        var s = super.intrinsicContentSize
        s.height = s.height + UIEI.top + UIEI.bottom
        s.width = s.width + UIEI.left + UIEI.right
        return s
    }
    
    override func drawText(in rect:CGRect) {
        let r = rect.inset(by: UIEI)
        super.drawText(in: r)
    }
    
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds:CGRect,
                               limitedToNumberOfLines n:Int) -> CGRect {
        let b = bounds
        let tr = b.inset(by: UIEI)
        let ctr = super.textRect(forBounds: tr, limitedToNumberOfLines: 0)
        // that line of code MUST be LAST in this function, NOT first
        return ctr
    }
}
```

Again, note that the answers on this and other QA that are "USUALLY" correct suffer the problem in the first image above - the ***"super is in the wrong place"***.

### Summary: you must "call super *last*" in textRect#forBounds

That's the secret.

Note that you ***do not need to*** additionally call `invalidate`, `sizeThatFits`, `needsLayout` or any other forcing call. The correct solution must and does work properly in the normal draw cycle.

Comment: Great solution. Could you please expand on why you are overwriting the `numberOfLines`?

Comment: I used this and the IBInspectable stuff from the highest-voted (but seemingly not as correct) answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368958/826946) and added support for border (color, thickness, cornerRadius) also using IBInspectable. It's over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317976/826946

Comment: Love how in 2021, you still aren't able to set a property on the `UILabel` to do this automatically.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but I'm unable to dynamically set the font size afterwards? It seems to shrink to 10 despite me setting it to something much higher, like 24. And when I disable this code, the size is correct. I should add that I'm in a tableview with a cell and label that I think is having it's instrinsic size adjusted, by the padding and by linespacing.

Comment: This did not work for me with text long enough to make it wrap to another line, at least when put into a SwiftUI stack, only one line is visible.

Comment: Chucky - could it be that you simply forgot to set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth correctly?  Works perfectly in many projects for us.  Jordan - it's very unlikely intrinsic size etc. would be broken in SwiftUI, did you catch the "don't forget" lines in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately this overrides my `numberOfLines` setting. I only need to show 2 lines (and `...` after that), but this just sets it to 0 and showed all text instead. If I remove the `numberOfLines` setting, it shows the correct lines set, but the spacing is wrong.

Comment: @Fattie I see your other answer that you warn works only for single line. But, where is the answer that works for 2 lines or any fixed number of lines?

Answer (score 23):

Without Storyboard:

```
class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    var topInset: CGFloat
    var bottomInset: CGFloat
    var leftInset: CGFloat
    var rightInset: CGFloat

    required init(withInsets top: CGFloat, _ bottom: CGFloat,_ left: CGFloat,_ right: CGFloat) {
        self.topInset = top
        self.bottomInset = bottom
        self.leftInset = left
        self.rightInset = right
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
            contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
            contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
            return contentSize
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
let label = PaddingLabel(8, 8, 16, 16)
label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
label.text = "Hello World"
label.backgroundColor = .black
label.textColor = .white
label.textAlignment = .center
label.layer.cornerRadius = 8
label.clipsToBounds = true
label.sizeToFit()

view.addSubview(label)
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Works, but do you know how to make it accept multiple lines? Just change init with "PaddingLabel(withInsets: 8, 8, 16, 16)"

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4+**

```
class EdgeInsetLabel: UILabel {
    var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
                                          left: -textInsets.left,
                                          bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
                                          right: -textInsets.right)
        return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let label = EdgeInsetLabel()
label.textInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 6, bottom: 2, right: 6)
```

Comment: WAIT - there's actually a problem I found with this in some cases. Previously this was the most correct answer. I've put in the correct answer below.

Comment: ***I have included an image in my answer showing the problem***

Answer (score 15):

Just use autolayout:

```
let paddedWidth = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width + 2 * padding
myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: paddedWidth).isActive = true
```

Done.

Comment: You can also do the same with height.

Answer (score 9):

As per **Swift 4.2** (Xcode 10 beta 6) "UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect" being deprecated.
I've also declared the class public to make it more useful.

```
public class UIPaddedLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    public override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
                      height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
    }

    public override func sizeToFit() {
        super.sizeThatFits(intrinsicContentSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well. But I try to use it inside a CollectionViewCell and it doesn't resize well after reuse (event after sizeToFit and layoutIfNeeded). Any id how to resize it?

Comment: I did update sizeToFit() to make it work with reusable view

Comment: `sizeToFit()` should be public as: "Overriding instance method must be as accessible as its enclosing type"

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3 Code with Implementation Example**

```
class UIMarginLabel: UILabel {

    var topInset:       CGFloat = 0
    var rightInset:     CGFloat = 0
    var bottomInset:    CGFloat = 0
    var leftInset:      CGFloat = 0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topInset, left: self.leftInset, bottom: self.bottomInset, right: self.rightInset)
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        return super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }
}

class LabelVC: UIViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var labelWithMargin: UIMarginLabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Label settings.
        labelWithMargin.leftInset = 10
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add class name UIMarginLabel in storyboard label object.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3

best and simple way

```
class UILabelPadded: UILabel {
     override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
     let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
     super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you use this code for your UILabel please?

Comment: Hi @David_2877 it's a class, just add this class into your project, and when you want UILabel use UILabelPadded. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 8):

Just like the other answers, but it fixes a bug:

When `label.width` is controlled by auto layout, sometimes text will be cropped.

```
@IBDesignable
class InsetLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 4.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 4.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 4.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 4.0

    var insets: UIEdgeInsets {
        get {
            return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        }
        set {
            topInset = newValue.top
            leftInset = newValue.left
            bottomInset = newValue.bottom
            rightInset = newValue.right
        }
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var adjSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        adjSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        adjSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        return adjSize
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let systemContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let adjustSize = CGSize(width: systemContentSize.width + leftInset + rightInset, height: systemContentSize.height + topInset +     bottomInset)
        if adjustSize.width > preferredMaxLayoutWidth && preferredMaxLayoutWidth != 0 {
            let constraintSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width - (leftInset + rightInset), height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            let newSize = super.sizeThatFits(constraintSize)
            return CGSize(width: systemContentSize.width, height: ceil(newSize.height) + topInset + bottomInset)
        } else {
            return adjustSize
        }
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist of the fix? What was changed or added? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53222793/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: this fails completely in all but the most trivial fixed cases

Answer (score 7):

I edited a little in the accepted answer. There is a problem when `leftInset` and `rightInset` increase, a part of text will be disappeared, b/c the width of label will be narrowed but the height does not increase as figure:

[image: padding label with wrong intrinsic content size]

To resolve this problem you need to re-calculate height of text as follow:

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

  @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 20.0
  @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 20.0
  @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 20.0
  @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 20.0

  override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
  }

  override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()

    let textWidth = frame.size.width - (self.leftInset + self.rightInset)
    let newSize = self.text!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(textWidth, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.font], context: nil)
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height = ceil(newSize.size.height) + self.topInset + self.bottomInset

    return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
  }
}
```

and result:

[image: padding label with right intrinsic content size]

I hope to help some people in the same situation as me.

Comment: If you plan to use **Swift 3.0**, you must change function names, as new Apple language completely breaks previous func definition.

So, `override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect)` becomes `override func drawText(in rect: CGRect)` and `override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize` becomes `override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize`

Enjoy!

Comment: unfortunately I did not make it work. I tried with our code swift 5  `override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
         // .. 
          return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }`

Answer (score 7):

Another option without subclassing would be to:

1. Set label `text`
2. `sizeToFit()`
3. then increase label height a little to simulate padding

   ```
   label.text = "someText"
   label.textAlignment = .center    
   label.sizeToFit()  
   label.frame = CGRect( x: label.frame.x, y: label.frame.y,width:  label.frame.width + 20,height: label.frame.height + 8)
   ```

Comment: Surprisingly, this was all I needed, just modified a little to this: `label.frame = CGRect( x: label.frame.origin.x - 10, y: label.frame.origin.y - 4, width:  label.frame.width + 20,height: label.frame.height + 8)` the -10 and -4 for centralizing

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3, iOS10 solution:

```
open class UIInsetLabel: UILabel {

    open var insets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets() {
        didSet {
            super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        size.width += insets.left + insets.right
        size.height += insets.top + insets.bottom
        return size
    }

    override open func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        return super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Subclass UILabel. (File-New-File- CocoaTouchClass-make Subclass of UILabel).

```
//  sampleLabel.swift

import UIKit

class sampleLabel: UILabel {

 let topInset = CGFloat(5.0), bottomInset = CGFloat(5.0), leftInset = CGFloat(8.0), rightInset = CGFloat(8.0)

 override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {

  let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
  super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))

 }
 override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
  var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
  intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
  intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
  return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
 }
}
```

On ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let labelName = sampleLabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 25))
  labelName.text = "Sample Label"
  labelName.backgroundColor =  UIColor.grayColor()

  labelName.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
  labelName.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  labelName.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
  self.view.addSubview(labelName)
 }
```

OR Associate custom UILabel class on Storyboard as Label's class.

Comment: i would up vote if you change those hardcoded values into class properties, i am already using this code.

Comment: @ Juan : drawTextInRect is a default class property of UILabel which we are unable to override using code. The best practice to subclass UILabel and add required frame change. Anyhow, it is convenient as Inheritance feature.

Comment: this is correct, however as of Swift 3 at least, intrinsicContentSize is not a function but rather a property, so should be "override var intrinsicContentSize: CGFloat {}" instead of "override func intrinsicContentSize", just a note.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5 Example with UILabel Extension

With the code below setting your margins is as easy as `label.setMargins(15)`.

```
extension UILabel {
    func setMargins(_ margin: CGFloat = 10) {
        if let textString = self.text {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = margin
            paragraphStyle.headIndent = margin
            paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -margin
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
            attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: @VladimirSukanica it is working on my end. I think the solution is just fine.

Comment: totally completely wrong unfortunately :)  only works in the simplest of cases

Comment: This does only indent my paragraph on the left (and maybe right, too). A label with a single line is not indented at the top and the bottom and neither a multiline label.

Answer (score 3):

An elaboration on [Mundi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel/27460983#27460983).

I.e., embedding a label in a `UIView` and enforcing padding through Auto Layout. Example:

[image: It looks like a padded UILabel]

**Overview:**

1. Create a `UIView` ("panel"), and set its appearance.
2. Create a `UILabel` and add it to the panel.
3. Add constraints to enforce padding.
4. Add the panel to your view hierarchy, and then position the panel.

**Details:**

1. Create the panel view.

   let panel = UIView()
   panel.backgroundColor = .green
   panel.layer.cornerRadius = 12
2. Create the label, add it to the panel as a subview.

   let label = UILabel()
   panel.addSubview(label)
3. Add constraints between the edges of the label and the panel. This forces the panel to keep a distance from the label. I.e., "padding".

*Editorial: doing all this by hand is super-tedious, verbose and error-prone. I suggest you pick an Auto Layout wrapper from GitHub or write one yourself*

```
label.panel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: panel.topAnchor,
    constant: vPadding).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: panel.bottomAnchor,
    constant: -vPadding).isActive = true
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: panel.leadingAnchor,
    constant: hPadding).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: panel.trailingAnchor,
    constant: -hPadding).isActive = true

label.textAlignment = .center
```

4. Add the panel to your view hierarchy and then add positioning constraints. E.g., hug the right-hand side of a tableViewCell, as in the example image.

*Note: you only need to add positional constraints, not dimensional constraints: Auto Layout will solve the layout based on both the `intrinsicContentSize` of the label and the constraints added earlier.*

```
hostView.addSubview(panel)
panel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
panel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostView.trailingAnchor,
    constant: -16).isActive = true
panel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code if you are facing a text trimming problem while applying padding.

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 5.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let textWidth = frame.size.width - (self.leftInset + self.rightInset)
        let newSize = self.text!.boundingRect(with: CGSize(textWidth, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.font], context: nil)
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height = ceil(newSize.size.height) + self.topInset + self.bottomInset
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }
}

extension CGSize{
    init(_ width:CGFloat,_ height:CGFloat) {
        self.init(width:width,height:height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting, I am looking for a solution regardin padding + trimming. It seems to me your solution breaks label.numberOfLines = 0 which I need. Any workaround?

Comment: @Don the only correct solution in all cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Answer (score 3):

## Strictly for SINGLE-LINE labels:  (2021 syntax)

For anyone googling here who needs padding on a STRICTLY SINGLE LINE label (such as a section heading or other list item),

The syntax has changed a lot. Beware out of date info on the internet.

Here's the exact class to copy and paste:

```
// add 100 above, 50 padding below a SINGLE-LINE label
import UIKit
class SingleLineLabelWithSpacing: UILabel {
    // STRICTLY for SINGLE LINE labels
    // only works with SINGLE LINE labels

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
               top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var ic = super.intrinsicContentSize
        ic.height = ic.height + 150
        return ic
    }
}
```

[image]

In the example, padding above/below of 100/50.

This is the usual thing to do when you have any sort of **scrolling list, feed, or other list**.

In this way you never have to think about the spacing above/below the headline, username, etc - you just drop it in the stack view or whatever the case is.

Also of course you can change the two values everywhere all at once when the designers want to tweak it.

Reminder: if you want to truly pad a UILabel **so that it works perfectly regardless of number of lines of text**, dynamic sizing cells, animations, etc etc etc, it is very complicated. The only correct answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `UILabel`

```
class UILabel : UIKit.UILabel {
    var insets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -insets.top,
                                          left: -insets.left,
                                          bottom: -insets.bottom,
                                          right: -insets.right)
        return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Easy padding (Swift 3.0, Alvin George answer):**

```
  class NewLabel: UILabel {

        override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
                return self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(15.0), dy: CGFloat(15.0))
        }

        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
                super.drawText(in: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(5.0), dy: CGFloat(5.0)))
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

One pragmatic solution is to add blank labels of the same height and color as the main label. Set the leading/trailing space to the main label to zero, align vertical centers, and make the width your desired margin.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want or need to use an @IBInspectable / @IBDesignable UILabel in Storyboard (I think those are rendered too slow anyway), then it is cleaner to use UIEdgeInsets instead of 4 different CGFloats.

**Code example for Swift 4.2:**

```
class UIPaddedLabel: UILabel {
    var padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    public override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: padding))
    }

    public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + padding.left + padding.right,
                      height: size.height + padding.top + padding.bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to what people answered but adds `sizeThatFits` to help `UIKit` to figure out the right size.

```
class InsetLabel : UILabel {
    @objc var textInsets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var s = super.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width - (textInsets.left + textInsets.right), height: size.height - (textInsets.top + textInsets.bottom)))
        s.height += textInsets.top + textInsets.bottom
        return s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers, but with a func class to setup the padding dinamically:

```
class UILabelExtendedView: UILabel
{
    var topInset: CGFloat = 4.0
    var bottomInset: CGFloat = 4.0
    var leftInset: CGFloat = 8.0
    var rightInset: CGFloat = 8.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect)
    {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
    {
        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return contentSize
    }

    func setPadding(top: CGFloat, left: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, right: CGFloat){
        self.topInset = top
        self.bottomInset = bottom
        self.leftInset = left
        self.rightInset = right
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.frame, insets))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Objective-C**

Based on [Tai Le's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368958/9516941), which implements the feature inside an [Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) Designable, here's the Objective-C version.

Put this in *YourLabel.h* file:

```
@interface YourLabel : UILabel

@property IBInspectable CGFloat topInset;
@property IBInspectable CGFloat bottomInset;
@property IBInspectable CGFloat leftInset;
@property IBInspectable CGFloat rightInset;

@end
```

And this would go in file *YourLabel.m*:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE

@implementation YourLabel

#pragma mark - Super

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.topInset = 0;
        self.bottomInset = 0;
        self.leftInset = 0;
        self.rightInset = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topInset, self.leftInset, self.bottomInset, self.rightInset);
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return CGSizeMake(size.width + self.leftInset + self.rightInset,
                      size.height + self.topInset + self.bottomInset);
}

@end
```

You can then modify YourLabel insets directly in Interface Builder after specifying the class inside the [XIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) file or storyboard, the default value of the insets being zero.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t seen this answer given anywhere. My technique is to set a width constraint on the label and adjust that width when setting the label text.

```
self.myLabel.text = myString;

UIFont * const font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightRegular]; // Change to your own label font.

CGSize const size = CGSizeMake(INFINITY, 18); // 18 is height of label.

CGFloat const textWidth = [myString boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil].size.width;

self.myLabelWidthConstraint.constant = textWidth + 20; // 10 padding on each side. Also, set text alignment to centre.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.addSubview(makeLabel("my title",x: 0, y: 100, w: 320, h: 30))
    }

    func makeLabel(title:String, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, w:CGFloat, h:CGFloat)->UILabel{
        var myLabel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x,y,w,h))
        myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

        // inser last char to right
        var titlePlus1char = "\(title)1"
        myLabel.text = titlePlus1char
        var titleSize:Int = count(titlePlus1char)-1

        myLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0,blue:1.0,alpha:1.0)
        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 214/255, green: 167/255, blue: 0/255,alpha:1.0)


        // create myMutable String
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

        // create myMutable font
        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titlePlus1char, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)!])

        // set margin size
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 10)!, range: NSRange(location: titleSize,length: 1))

        // set last char to alpha 0
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0,blue:1.0,alpha:0), range: NSRange(location: titleSize,length: 1))

        myLabel.attributedText = myMutableString

        return myLabel
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy padding:**

```
import UIKit

    class NewLabel: UILabel {

        override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {

            return CGRectInset(self.bounds, CGFloat(15.0), CGFloat(15.0))
        }

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

            super.drawTextInRect(CGRectInset(self.bounds,CGFloat(5.0), CGFloat(5.0)))
        }

    }
```

Comment: 3.0 version on bottom page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 2px padding around the textRect, just do this:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: -2, bottom: -2, right: -2)
label.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textRect, insets)
```

Comment: what is textRect? label.frame?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 10

// Swift 4.2++
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Your text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])

// Swift 4.1--
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Your text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5

On the method layoutSubviews() change the inserts of your UILabel as bellow.

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    label.frame = label.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10))
  }
```

Comment: @Fattie It works for me and it may work for someone else if other people are suggesting the same answer.

Comment: Ciao Kivia, I'm afraid it honestly does not work - it only works in the simplest test examples where it's not part of a layout, the label is not constrained in any way to other elements around it, and the text is not set on the fly. iOS is a pain!!!!

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly for me.

```
class PaddedLabel: UILabel {
    var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        let insetRect = bounds.inset(by: textInsets)
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: insetRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top, left: -textInsets.left, bottom: -textInsets.bottom, right: -textInsets.right)
        return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

If you're looking for just left and right padding, you can simply add empty spaces before and after the text:

```
titleLabel.text = " \(categoryName) "
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work. iOS actually *removes* any trailing spaces.  here's a discussion about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813420/294884

Comment: It works man, please see the updated answer and change your down vote

Comment: Badr, *it indeed removes TRAILING spaces*, Means, at the end of the string.  `= " \(categoryName) "` .. try it

Comment: It still works, I updated the answer. It probably not the exact number of empty spaces, but leading and trailing spaces are working in my case.