# Change a UIButton's text (padding) programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

Still learning Swift and don't know Objective-C. I saw that in order to changing a button's text programmatically requires the use of `titleEdgeInsets` but I am not really sure how to use it.

I would like to change the text in the button (padding) in the bottom and both the left and the right.

Thanks for any responses and/or examples!

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Still valid for:
`iOS 12/Xcode 10/Swift 4.2/OSX 10.13.2`

---

`iOS 9.1/Xcode 7.1/Swift 2.1/OSX 10.10.5`:

The method `titleEdgeInsets` didn't work for me.  My button's frame tightly hugs the text (I didn't specify a frame size), and the frame has a red background color.  After doing:

```
 myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)
```

the red background shrunk inwards by 10 pixels on each side, which meant that now some of the text was outside the red background.  Using negative values had no effect on the original frame size.

I was able to get padding around the text, effectively making the frame bigger, by doing:

```
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)
```

Comment: new method is called: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: #, left:#, :bottom: #,  right: #)

Comment: @Andrea, UIEdgeInsetsMake() is still in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624475-uiedgeinsetsmake?language=occ

Comment: @Andrea, Do you get a warning if you call `UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)` ?

Comment: `titleEdgeInsets` is deprecated in iOS 15 :(

Answer (score 63):

iOS 10 and Swift 3 example

Tested and works on IOS 11 and Swift 4.

```
refineButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: If the text is truncating, while use of `titleEdgeInsets`, replace it to `contentEdgeInsets`.

Comment: Note, `contentEdgeInsets` is deprecated in iOS 15

Answer (score 31):

You can add padding from top, left, right and bottom by doing these lines of code.

```
button.titleEdgeInsets.left = 10; // add left padding.
button.titleEdgeInsets.right = 10; // add right padding.
button.titleEdgeInsets.top = 10; // add top padding.
button.titleEdgeInsets.bottom = 10; // add bottom padding.
```

Answer (score 27):

You can also do this in the storyboard:
[image]

Comment: The question specified "programmatically"

Comment: I don't pretend to a best answer. Just for fullness of information.

Comment: It was useful, @aeid sometimes I search "programmatically" because I couldn't find it in the storyboard

Comment: I didn't search for programmatically or storyboard, because I don't care either way. Glad to know it's there

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 9.1/Xcode 7.1/Swift 2.1

```
@IBOutlet weak var ratingButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ratingButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:15,right:10,bottom:15,left:10)

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 15 `contentEdgeInsets` is deprecated so you need to use the following...

```
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain() // there are several options to choose from instead of .plain()
configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 24, bottom: 24, trailing: 24)
button.configuration = configuration
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use a custom class if you don't want to define the properties everytime you create a button;

```
class UIPaddedButton: UIButton {
  let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return contentRect.inset(by: padding)
  }
}
```

And when initializing;

```
let btn = UIPaddedButton()
```

Comment: this is **not really correct.** adjusting the titleRect is quite difficult. you have to follow a procedure similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876988/294884

Answer (score -1):

For xcode 13.4 and iOS 12
Tested and working
To make space to both sides of a button

```
ButtonName.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
```

Comment: unfortunately completely wrong, deprecated away :/