# iOS 11: Height of UINavigationBar for large title (mimic Apple Music App)

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11

I'm trying to mimic the look of `UINavigationBar` as used by the Apple Music App (the date is shown above the large title).

I know that the Apple Music App doesn't use the standard `UINavigationBar` of [ios11](/questions/tagged/ios11) but a header view is `UICollectionView`.

I also want to use the standard `UINavigationBar` of [ios11](/questions/tagged/ios11) because of the resizing feature for title text.

I'm able to add the `custom date label` to view hierarchy of the large `title view`, my code as shown below:

```
    self.title = "Large Title"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }

    // Create label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Small Title"

    // Add label to subview hierarchy
    for subview in navigationBar.subviews {
        let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
        if stringFromClass.contains("UINavigationBarLargeTitleView") {
            subview.addSubview(label)
        }
    }

    // Add label constraints
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leftAnchor, constant: 16.0),
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -50.0),
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0)
        ])
```

The `custom date label` is placed correctly but I'm unable to set the height of `UINavigationBar` to additional `height` of the label.

[image: Large Title]

Since [ios11](/questions/tagged/ios11) `UINavigationBar` uses Auto-layout, so setting the frame wont work anymore as like the previous iOS versions.

The Auto-layout constraints added by the system. by default it have a priority of 1000, so adding the additional constraints to the label didn't give any effect or result in the Auto-layout conflict.

Any hints to show the "Small Title" above the "Large Title" without scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play a little bit with the `UILabel` inside the `UINavigationBarLargeTitleView` like change its Insets and reduce font size, here is an example:

```
        // Create label
        labelSubtitle.text = "Small Title"
        labelSubtitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        labelSubtitle.textColor = UIColor.searchBarTextColor(dark: theme)
        labelSubtitle.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

        // Add label to subview hierarchy
        for subview in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
            let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
            if stringFromClass.contains("UINavigationBarLargeTitleView") {

                let largeSubViews = subview.subviews
                for sbv in largeSubViews
                {
                    if let lbl = sbv as? UILabel
                    {
                        lbl.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                        lbl.setNeedsLayout()
                    }
                }
                subview.addSubview(labelSubtitle)
            }
        }

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)]

        labelSubtitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelSubtitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelSubtitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -37.0),
            labelSubtitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            labelSubtitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0)
            ])
```

To change the insets I'm using an extension published on in this post: [Adding space/padding to a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145859/3770254)

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly .. Tnx.