# Add padding to a general View programmatically with swift

Tags: ios, swift, padding

Is there a "general syntax" for add a padding on any `UIView` created programmatically in Swift?

For example I've created a `UITextField()` and a `UILabel()`, is there a common method to add to them a padding?

Comment: Are you talking about how do you make a text field and a label with a space in-between? If you are, have a [look at constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368958/4637057