# How to align the text inside UILabel at the bottom of UILabel frame?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Text inside the label is aligned centered horizontally as well as vertically. How do I set the text to align below the mid horizontal axis?

Comment: picture speak better than words

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding space/padding to a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel)

Comment: Question wording is different but this answer will resolve the issue.

Comment: Use label insets programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by subclassing UILabel and override this method

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIEdgeInsets insets = {6, 5, 0, 5};//{top, left,bottom,right} Change the padding values as your need
 [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. But this is the simplest one.

Create a UIView

Add that Label into that view

Add auto layout constraint to define fixed margin from the bottom of the view.