# How to resize UILabel width to fit text using autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UILabel with the following constraints

```
Height = 30
Leading = superview leading
Center Y = superview center Y
```

Text of the label changes based on api response. I was using `label.sizeToFit()` to change the width of the label.

Now I want to add some space to the label. New width should be

```
textsize + 50
```

How can I do this without calculating the width, only using autolayout.

Comment: have you tried to use `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth =  true`

Comment: @MohmmadS I don't have width constraint for the label. Its size increases based on the text. I want to have some padding now. Like `|    Hello    |`. Dont want `|Hello|`

Comment: look around offset then

Comment: @MohmmadS If I use `offset` the text truncates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel
Check this answer, maybe it can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We generally do not add padding to a label. We use another solution:

1. You can increase leading and trailing constraints from 0 to whatever you need.
2. You can create another `UIView` on which you place your label. The label should have leading and trailing constraints as much as you want your padding. This should automatically resize your view
3. Use `UIButton` which already has content insets in Storyboard. Disable its user interaction. (It is an overkill but it is A solution).

If you really really want this though you can create a subclass of `UILabel` and add this functionality in just few lines:

```
@IBDesignable class AppLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() } }
    @IBInspectable var verticalPadding: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() } }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        size.width += horizontalPadding*2.0
        size.height += verticalPadding*2.0
        return size
    }

}
```

Now you can even in storyboard set vertical and horizontal padding. But you need to have center text alignment. The key is overriding `intrinsicContentSize` which is what defines this automatic sizing. Simply some value is added to it and it works.

I would personally still avoid this but perhaps it is still better than using `UIButton`.

Comment: I knew these solutions. Tried to find more simple solution. Finally ended up with 3rd solution

Comment: @arunsiva I actually added a 4th solution. Maybe in your case it is still better than the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that UILabel inside a UIView and give constraints(padding) to that view.

Answer (score 0):

In swift

```
yourtextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
yourtextLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```