# iOS 14 and Simulator UILabel extension padding bug

Tags: ios, uilabel, padding, ios14, uiedgeinsets

I use this UILabel extension for label padding in a lot of areas in my projects. And it works perfectly on iOS 13 and older version devices. But it doesn't work at all on iOS 14 devices and Simulators. How can I solve this problem at least on iOS 14?

I found this solution years ago from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145859/7825024

This is my code:

```
extension UILabel {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var padding = UIEdgeInsets()
    }
    
    public var padding: UIEdgeInsets? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding) as? UIEdgeInsets
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.padding, newValue as UIEdgeInsets?, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let insets = padding {
            self.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
        } else {
            self.drawText(in: rect)
        }
    }
    
    override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let text = self.text else { return super.intrinsicContentSize }
        
        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        var textWidth: CGFloat = frame.size.width
        var insetsHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        if let insets = padding {
            textWidth -= insets.left + insets.right
            insetsHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom
        }
        
        let newSize = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: ([.font: self.font ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]), context: nil)
        
        contentSize.height = ceil(newSize.size.height) + insetsHeight
        
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange but I found the solution. This code works on Simulator and iOS 14 devices when Xcode 12 does deselect "Debug executable".

In Xcode 12, I was deselect the "Debug executable" part because sometimes compiling took a long time. That way I noticed my padding code was working. It is interesting, but for now, I will use it this way while release the app.

The solution is to deselect this:

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ... -> Run -> Info -> Debug
> executable