# Collectionview No padding on cell label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to build a collection view on a page which has 2 sections.  I want the section 1 cells to be coloured yellow and the section 2 cells to be coloured blue.

I have managed to get the collectionview cells to show up - however the cells don't appear to have any padding between them - and where the background colour ends.  How do I add more coloured padding around the cells to make them look tidier? ( ideally with interface builder)
Screenshot:
[image: Collectionview no padding]

Edit: After adding Edge Insets to my custom cell - it gets me closer to what I am after but seems to truncate the text - and remove my rounded corners:

Code:

```
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }
```

[image: Insets]

Is there a way to get UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize to take into account the extra 10 width and keep the rounded corners ( when using insets)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, you can adjust line spacing and item spacing in Interface Builder by setting properties of your layout instance.

You can find layout instance right below/within your `UICollectionView` instance in left pane of Interface Builder.

1. Open Interface Builder
2. Find `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object within `UICollectionView`
3. Select `Size Inspector` tab in right pane
4. Change `Min Spacing`

Note: That will leave some space between your cells. If you wanna change content insets of your cells or labels, you should use custom cells.
To add content insets to your `UILabel`s, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin) and/or [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel)

Comment: thanks so much @Mert- actually the last point is what I am after- how do I change the content insets if I have a custom cell already( which I have)

Comment: then your question becomes "how to add contentInsets to UILabel?". there are already many questions on this in SO, i added two of them to the answer. hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Mert - I tried out the first solution - and it seems to truncate everything) ( have added this to the question above ) so you can see the out put - I guess I need to do more work with overiding the intrinsic content size. This seems like a lot of work for what should be a simple, common use case.  Hope I am just missing something.

Comment: exactly. your label draws the text but when autolayout engine asks for its content size, it returns a smaller size so that it ends up truncated. i'm sorry i can't explain that in detail here but i suggest googling autolayout to have a general idea

Comment: Thanks it was down to this SO ticket in the end that helped solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167226/resizing-a-uilabel-to-accomodate-insets/21267507#21267507.  Appreciate the help though Mert- Do you want to update your answer and I will mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `UIView` first on your cell by setting its constraints and then add your labels in that view.

at last give appropriate colour to cell, UIView, labels as per your choice.

Comment: Thanks - but adding a view around the cell - doesn't let me add more padding within the cell itself. ( see the screenshot above)

Comment: You may set UIView constraints to cell with desire constraintsConstant(i.e leading, trailing, top and bottom to 5 for example)

Comment: this will lead to more color padding but now i got to know that you want simple Spacing between cells