# C# Xamarin Label Padding for iOS app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I know this question has been asked a lot but I've tried the various solutions and can't seem to find one that works.  I have a label on my storyboard titled Messages. On button click, different text appears in the label. I need to pad just this label.

I've looked at:
[Adding space/padding to a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel?rq=1),
[UILabel text margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin),
and [Resizing a UILabel to accommodate insets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167226/resizing-a-uilabel-to-accommodate-insets).

Also not sure where in my ViewController.cs to put the code.  I put it under `public partial class ViewController : UIViewController` but get errors.

**Edit 2:**

Okay, at first I did a UITextView but couldn't get vertical align to work so went back to label. This is what I have:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{

    public partial class PaddedUILabel : UILabel
    {
        private UIEdgeInsets EdgeInsets { get; set; }

        public PaddedUILabel()
        {
            EdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 10, 0, 10);
        }
        public override void DrawText(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {
            base.DrawText(EdgeInsets.InsetRect(rect));
        }
    }

public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Message.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        Message.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(1, 0.88f);
        PaddedUILabel _paddedUILabel = Message as PaddedUILabel;
```

I'm still not getting any padding.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin iOS or Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Xamarin iOS. The answer below to use `UITextView` works but now the text is not vertically aligned.

Comment: Are you using SizeToFit in your code? if yes please remove it and try

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a UITextView and provide the insets directly (as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27461090/2974780)) which you can do either in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear, or you can [subclass your UILabel](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/api_design/nsobject_generics/) and override the [DrawText method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel.DrawText/p/System.Drawing.RectangleF/).

The DrawText method helps manipulate the rectangle in which the text within a label is drawn. I'd suggest you pay around with some values to get started with it.

Something like:

```
public partial class PaddedUILabel : UILabel
{
     //Override draw text here

}
```

If you are using Xamarin iOS Native, give your label(for example: myLabel) the custom class from story board and retrieve the label as:

```
PaddedUILabel _paddedUILabel = this.myLabel as PaddedUILabel;
```

I'm sorry I would have given you the whole code but as of now, don't have access to a Mac environment. Let me know if you need anything else.

For vertical align in TextView follow [link](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/).

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this so I used the other suggestion of using UITextView, which works but now I don't know how to get the text to vertically align?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

i tried many solutions as discussed here but the actual out coming not what i wanted so i made it like that :

```
 if (this.Padding != default(Thickness))
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                      {

                          if (Parent is Grid)
                          {
                              var parentAsGrid = Parent as Grid;
                              var index = parentAsGrid.Children.IndexOf(this);
                              parentAsGrid.Children.Remove(this);
                              Grid marginGrid = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor,  HorizontalOptions = this.HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions = this.VerticalOptions };


                              var lbl = new Label() { Text = this.Text, TextColor = this.TextColor, BackgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor, HorizontalOptions = this.HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions = this.VerticalOptions, FontSize = this.FontSize };
                              lbl.Margin = this.Padding;
                              if (!parentAsGrid.Children.Contains(this))
                              {
                                  marginGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
                                  parentAsGrid.Children.Insert(index, marginGrid);
                              }

                          }
                          if (Parent is StackLayout)
                          {
                              var parentAsGrid = Parent as StackLayout;
                              var index = parentAsGrid.Children.IndexOf(this);
                              parentAsGrid.Children.Remove(this);
                              Grid marginGrid = new Grid() { BackgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor,   HorizontalOptions = this.HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions = this.VerticalOptions };


                              var lbl = new Label() { Text = this.Text, TextColor = this.TextColor, BackgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor, HorizontalOptions = this.HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions = this.VerticalOptions, FontSize = this.FontSize };
                              lbl.Margin = this.Padding;
                              if (!parentAsGrid.Children.Contains(this))
                              {
                                  marginGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
                                  parentAsGrid.Children.Insert(index, marginGrid);
                              }

                          }



                      });
```