# Calculate actual text frame of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

i have an extension to UILabel that suppose to calculate it's frame.

```
func getFrameWithAlreadySetTextAndFont() -> CGRect {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = self.text
    label.font = self.font
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.frame.size.width = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    label.frame.size.height = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame
  }
```

Now, i want to calculate expected text frame for my label.

```
let lbl = LabelSL.extraLarge()
lbl.text = "357"
let expectedLabelFrame = lbl.getFrameWithAlreadySetTextAndFont()
```

Ok, i got:

```
expected frame (0.0, 0.0, 42.5, 29.0)
```

[image]

That is frame of label i can see in debugger.

But what i actually want is text frame:

[image]

The same as previous, but without extra spaces. How can i get it?

Comment: Have you tried [`textRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620545-textrect) or [`boundingRect `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect)

Comment: @dahiya_boy just tried, it still have same output.

Comment: This answer on stackoverflow should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/21267507/3564632 coming from this article: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/04/swift-extending-uilabel/.

Comment: Also this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel/44145859#44145859

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing a UILabel to accommodate insets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167226/resizing-a-uilabel-to-accommodate-insets)